# Simplify the expression and find the minimum value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to simplify the expression
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\Big[\sqrt{(1+x)^3} + \sqrt{(1-x)^3}  \Big]}{2-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}
\end{equation}
and find the minimum value of $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}A+\frac{1}{x}$.

I can only simplify to this point
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{2x\Big( 2-\sqrt{1-x^2} \Big)}{2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}.
\end{equation}
However, I am not sure if I can go any further. The next part of the question is to find the minimum value of $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}A+\frac{1}{x}$, which is obviously not so easy since I am not supposed to use differentiation to find optimal values.

Comment: if $x$ can be any value in(-1,1), then A have limitation, but 1/x don't have globe max or min. which means the min you want to get is only local min. Are you sure that is your question?

Comment: This problem was given to me as it is, and I can only use pre-cal to solve. However, you're right. I looked at the graph, and it seemed we only have local min in $[-1,1]$. $\frac{1}{2}$ seems to be its local min.

Comment: If we restrict to $0<x\leq 1$, we have a minimum value.

Comment: the min will be got at $x=0.6$ roughly. I don't think precaculus can  solve it. you may have to use numeric method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: $u = \sqrt{1+x}, v = \sqrt{1-x} \to \sqrt{1-x^2} = uv, 2 = u^2+v^2$, and consider $f(u,v) = ...$

Comment: I let $x=\sin 2\theta$ and get to $\displaystyle \frac{2\sin 2\theta(2-|\cos 2\theta|)}{2\sqrt{2}-|\sin\theta + \cos\theta| + |\sin\theta - \cos\theta|}$. Then what should I do next? Thank you.

Comment: What is the mistake? I checked, but couldn't see it. If I assume the interval for $\theta$, I can get rid of the abs value.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not simplify any further. This problem is hard.

Comment: I think you need to do it in two steps, ...i will get back on this a few hours....